# xskak / xsavebox: How to use an xsavebox for markmoves-list

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, xsavebox

I tried to use `xsaveboxes` at `markmoves`:

```
\xsbox{list1}{a8-e4}
\chessboard[tinyboard, 
markmoves=\xusebox{list1}% <--- error
]
```

so that I can use numbered boxes. 
But this does not work, what do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard} 
\setchessboard{showmover=false, pgfstyle=straightmove, color=red,} 

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=A, setwhite={Ba8}]
\mainline{1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}

\section{def works}
\def\List{a8-e4}
List: \List
\chessboard[tinyboard, markmoves=\List]

\section{xsavebox works not}
\xsbox{list1}{a8-e4}
list1: \xusebox{list1}
\chessboard[tinyboard, 
%markmoves=\xusebox{list1}<----- error!
]
\end{document}
```

Comment: An [x]savebox stores ***typeset*** text, not verbatim input useable as a command argument.

Comment: Ok, clear. Is this solveable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, standard LaTeX saveboxes and those created with the `xsavebox` package store readily typeset material to be re-inserted in the document at later locations. They cannot be used to store verbatim text for use as command arguments. To solve this, moves can be saved in two ways, using the same name:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard} 
\setchessboard{showmover=false, pgfstyle=straightmove, color=red,} 

\makeatletter
\def\mynamedef#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\let\mynameuse\@nameuse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=A, setwhite={Ba8}]
\mainline{1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}

\section{xsavebox and namedef}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mynamedef{list1}{a8-e4}
\xsbox{list1}{a8-e4}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
list1: \xusebox{list1}
\chessboard[tinyboard, 
markmoves=\mynameuse{list1}
]
\end{document}
```

But, after all, I would use just `\mynamedef` to store the text in verbatim, and to insert it for typesetting or as a command argument when needed. Using a savebox is perhaps a bit too much in the present case:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard} 
\setchessboard{showmover=false, pgfstyle=straightmove, color=red,} 

\makeatletter
\def\mynamedef#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\let\mynameuse\@nameuse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=A, setwhite={Ba8}]
\mainline{1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}

\section{namedef alone}
\mynamedef{List 1}{a8-e4}
List 1: \mynameuse{List 1}
\chessboard[tinyboard, 
markmoves=\mynameuse{List 1}
]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Got some problems when creating `\mynamedef`s  with a foreach-loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's because `\@namedef` is not global and therefore scoped within the group that `\foreach` establishes (the same problem that you had in a recent question of yours). I am going to replace the `\mynamedef` definition.

Comment: Now it works fine. See here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635845/46023